# Recursive Division algorithm for maze generation in android

Tags: android, algorithm, recursion, implementation, division

I have the java code for Recursive Division algorithm that generate a perfect maze but the problem is i want to implement it and cant find out a way to print the generated maze in android ... since it generates an array of characters for vertical lines "|" and another for horizontal lines "-".
i tried to loop on both arrays and draw a vertical line if "|" and a horizontal line if "-" but obviously that didn't work because i cant set the right positions of the lines on the android activity.
So how can i set the positions to draw the maze exactly as generated ?
OR is their another implementation for the algorithm on android ?

That's the implementation i use:

```
package com.jforeach.mazegame;

import java.util.*;
import android.util.Log;

class RecursiveDivision
{

    static final char VWALL = '|';
    static final char HWALL = '-';

    static final char MAZE_PATH = ' ';

    int rows;
    int cols;
    int act_rows;
    int act_cols;

    char[][] board;

    public RecursiveDivision(int row, int col)
    {

        //initialize instance variables
        rows = row*2+1;
        cols = col*2+1;
        act_rows = row;
        act_cols = col;
        board = new char[rows][cols];

        //set the maze to empty     
     /*   for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                board[i][j] = MAZE_PATH;
            }
        }*/

        //make the outter walls
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            board[i][0] = VWALL;
            board[i][cols-1] = VWALL;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<cols; i++){
            board[0][i] = HWALL;
            board[rows-1][i] = HWALL;
        }


    }

    //storefront method to make the maze
    public void makeMaze()
    {
        makeMaze(0,cols-1,0,rows-1);
        makeOpenings();


    }

    //behind the scences actual mazemaking
    private void makeMaze(int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
    {
        int width = right-left;
        int height = bottom-top;

        //makes sure there is still room to divide, then picks the best
        //direction to divide into
        if(width > 2 && height > 2){

            if(width > height)
                divideVertical(left, right, top, bottom);

            else if(height > width)
                divideHorizontal(left, right, top, bottom);

            else if(height == width){
                Random rand = new Random();
                boolean pickOne = rand.nextBoolean();

                if(pickOne)
                    divideVertical(left, right, top, bottom);
                else
                    divideHorizontal(left, right, top, bottom);
            }
        }else if(width > 2 && height <=2){
            divideVertical(left, right, top, bottom);
        }else if(width <=2 && height > 2){
            divideHorizontal(left, right, top, bottom);
        }
    }

    private void divideVertical(int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        //find a random point to divide at
        //must be even to draw a wall there
        int divide =  left + 2 + rand.nextInt((right-left-1)/2)*2;

        //draw a line at the halfway point
        for(int i=top; i<bottom; i++){
            board[i][divide] = VWALL;
        }

        //get a random odd integer between top and bottom and clear it
        int clearSpace = top + rand.nextInt((bottom-top)/2) * 2 + 1;

        board[clearSpace][divide] = MAZE_PATH;

        makeMaze(left, divide, top, bottom);
        makeMaze(divide, right, top, bottom);
    }

    private void divideHorizontal(int left, int right, int top, int bottom)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        //find a random point to divide at
        //must be even to draw a wall there
        int divide =  top + 2 + rand.nextInt((bottom-top-1)/2)*2;
        if(divide%2 == 1)
            divide++;

        //draw a line at the halfway point
        for(int i=left; i<right; i++){
            board[divide][i] = HWALL;
        }

        //get a random odd integer between left and right and clear it
        int clearSpace = left + rand.nextInt((right-left)/2) * 2 + 1;

        board[divide][clearSpace] = MAZE_PATH;

        //recur for both parts of the newly split section
        makeMaze(left, right, top, divide);
        makeMaze(left, right, divide, bottom);
    }

    public void makeOpenings(){

        Random rand = new Random(); //two different random number generators
        Random rand2 = new Random();//just in case

        //a random location for the entrance and exit
       int entrance_row = rand.nextInt(act_rows-1) * 2 +1;
       int exit_row = rand2.nextInt(act_rows-1) * 2 +1;

        //clear the location
        board[entrance_row][0] = MAZE_PATH;
        board[exit_row][cols-1] = MAZE_PATH;

    }

    public void printMaze()
    {           
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){

                Log.d("MAZE",  i +" "+ j+" "+ String.valueOf(board[i][j]));

            }
        }
    }


    public Maze getMaze()
    {
        Maze maze = convert();
        return maze;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maze generating algorithm works pretty well. Note that final `board` array has 4 possible characters in it: pipe, minus, space and 0 ascii character. I noticed that there is really no true distinction between walls as you can treat them as blocks. So maybe instead of drawing lines you should draw filled rectangles. Take a look at this function that prints the maze:

```
public void printMaze2()
{           
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            System.out.print((board[i][j]));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void printMaze3()
{           
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            if (board[i][j]==MAZE_PATH) System.out.print(" ");
            else if (board[i][j]==VWALL) System.out.print("#");
            else if (board[i][j]==HWALL) System.out.print("#");
            else System.out.print(" "); // this last case is for \0 
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but printing the maze in the console is not the problem, my problem is i want to draw it in android activity.
i tried using drawLine function but this method failed i think because of the postions is not well set for the android activity.

Comment: Rami, did you try to draw rectangles instead of lines. Sth like this: ```for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
if (board[i][j]==VWALL || if (board[i][j]==HWALL) 
canvas.drawRect(i*10, j*10, i*10+10, j*10+10, paint);``` ?

Comment: OHH that worked very well Thanks alot .. it's printed exactly as generated now but somehow small but that my least worries ! thanks alot :d

Comment: ```*10```, and ```+10``` define rectangle's dimensions. Change it to some variable to adjust rectangle size.